# How are favorite foods determined in Miitopia?

Tags: miitopia

In Miitopia, you’re able to feed characters different foods collected as enemy drops, which increase the characters’ stats depending on the food. How much those stats increase depends on how much the character likes these foods, ranging from absolutely hating the food (seems to give about 50% of normal increase) to absolutely loving the food (seems to give about 150% of normal increase).

What determines what foods a character likes or dislikes? Does it depend on the job, or some other characteristic of the character, or is it randomly generated?

Answer (score 2):

From all theories tested, it seems the id theory is the most valid one (pretty random) :

**The food preferences are tied to an internal ID code unique to a Mii, and the Mii Maker and Tomodachi Life versions of the same Mii may have different IDs.**

This means it does not depend on the job and that if you scan  it it will have the same preferences.
This was discussed and tested here :

https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/195500-miitopia/75768968